# SSH to Server from A YES, from B, NO

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, ssh

SO I have a ubuntu server hosted elsewhere - it is 1 day old and a clean install of ubuntu the firewall is inactive.  No failban etc.

I can ssh into it from laptop B - easy.

However laptop A ....

- I cannot ping the server, it times out.
- Cannot ssh to server.port 22: Connection timed out
- I have tried Putty - connection times out.
- I have turned off laptop A firewall in an effort to exclude this.
- I have confirmed both laptops are on the same default gateway.
- Both laptops can ping each other  back and forth.
- I have tried swapping out the successful DHCP assigned IP address for the working laptops address.
- I have (long overdue anyway) installed windows 11 on Laptop A in an effort to refresh everything.
- I have reset all network settings.

Comment: are A, B and Ubuntu in the same network?

Comment: can we get an ipconfig/ifconfig of all 3 machines as an edit?